# Convert array of objects with parent ids to a nested tree structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, javascript-objects

I have a mock JSON like below:

```
const apiData = [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    }
]
```

and I need to convert it to below:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 0,
        "children": [{
                "id": 5,
                "label": "List item 1",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "label": "List item 1",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "label": "List item 1",
                "parent_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "label": "List item 1",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "children": [{
                        "id": 9,
                        "label": "List item 1",
                        "parent_id": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "label": "List item 1",
                        "parent_id": 8
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 0
    }
]
```

The condition based on which we need to make changes is as follows:
if corresponding to a particular id, if we have a `parent_id` then we need to add one property `children` in the individual object and put values as an array of matched `parent_id` object.

I tried writing code for this and I came very close but I am unable to move forward.

Kindly suggest.

My code:

```
const apiData = [
{'id': 1, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 0 },
{'id': 5, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 1 },
{'id': 6, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 1 },
{'id': 7, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 1 },
{'id': 8, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 1},
{'id': 9, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 8 },
{'id': 10, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 8 },
{'id': 2, 'label': 'List item 1', 'parent_id' : 0 },
];

function compare(a, b) {
  const idA = a.id;
  const idB = b.id;
  let comparison = 0;
  comparison = idA > idB ? 1 : (idA < idB ? -1 : 0);
  return comparison;
}

const sortedApiData = apiData.sort(compare);
const newSortedApiData = [...sortedApiData];
let a = []; 


for(let i = 0; i < sortedApiData.length ; i++){
  for(let j = 0 ; j < sortedApiData.length ; j++){
     if(i === j){
       continue;
     }
     else{
       if(sortedApiData[i].id === sortedApiData[j].parent_id){
         a.push(sortedApiData[j]);

       }
     }
  }

}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Just FYI, JSON is a term used to refer to strings. Once JSON has been parsed into an in-memory data structure, it's just a plain old JS object. The desired result you want here is an n-ary tree.

Comment: did you see my new answer below ?

Comment: Yeah i saw your answer and i accepted it. Thanks a lot for this beautiful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a similar case like this one, but with jso items.
[Javascript list loop/recursion to create an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673573/javascript-list-loop-recursion-to-create-an-object/59675093#59675093)
items are assumed to be in good working order

```js
const apiData =
      [ { id: 1,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 0 }
      , { id: 5,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 1 }
      , { id: 6,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 1 }
      , { id: 7,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 1 }
      , { id: 8,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 1 }
      , { id: 9,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 8 }
      , { id: 10, label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 8 }
      , { id: 2,  label: 'List item 1',  parent_id: 0 }
      ];

const expected = 
      [ { id: 1, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 0, children: 
          [ { id: 5, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 1 } 
          , { id: 6, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 1 } 
          , { id: 7, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 1 } 
          , { id: 8, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 1, children: 
              [ { id: 9,  label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 8 } 
              , { id: 10, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 8 } 
        ] } ] } 
      , { id: 2, label: 'List item 1', parent_id: 0 } 
      ]; 
  
let output = []
  , pArr   = [{arr:output,id:0}]
  ;
for (let el of apiData)
  {
  let idx = pArr.findIndex(p=>p.id===el.parent_id);
  if(!Array.isArray(pArr[idx].arr))
    { pArr[idx].arr = pArr[idx].arr.children = [] }
  pArr[idx].arr.push(nv = Object.assign({}, el) )
  pArr[++idx] = { arr: nv, id:el.id }  // possible parent
  }

console.log ('output is expected ?', (JSON.stringify(output) === JSON.stringify(expected)))
console.log( 'output', output )
```

"for the record" : I made the same code but placed inside an Array.prototype.reduce :

```
let result = apiData.reduce((pArr,el,ix)=>
  {
  if (Number.isInteger(pArr))   // on ix===0
    { pArr = [{arr:[],id:0,ln:--pArr}]}

  let idx = pArr.findIndex(p=>p.id===el.parent_id);
  if(!Array.isArray(pArr[idx].arr))
    { pArr[idx].arr = pArr[idx].arr.children = [] }

  pArr[idx].arr.push(nv = Object.assign({}, el) )
  pArr[++idx] = { arr: nv, id:el.id }  // possible parent

  return (ix<pArr[0].ln) ? pArr : pArr[0].arr
  }
  , apiData.length ); 

// proof:
console.log ('result is expected ?', (JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expected)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build the result tree by walking the array once and assigning nodes to an object that contains nodes by id, creating children arrays as necessary.

After building the tree, assuming the data is well-formed and there is at least one node whose parent id does not exist in the tree (in your data array, there is no such `id: "0"` node), return that node's children. Sorting is only necessary if each level should be ordered in a particular way.

It's a bit more complicated if the data is not well formed; in that case, the result should be the merged children of every node that references a nonexistent parent, but I'll omit this until motivation is present.

Lastly, since the `sort` and `reduce` operations mutate the input, we can call `.map(e => ({...e}))` to create a copy and keep the function pure.

```js
const unflatten = data => {
  const tree = data.map(e => ({...e}))
    .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
    .reduce((a, e) => {
      a[e.id] = a[e.id] || e;
      a[e.parent_id] = a[e.parent_id] || {};
      const parent = a[e.parent_id];
      parent.children = parent.children || [];
      parent.children.push(e);
      return a;
    }, {})
  ;
  return Object.values(tree)
    .find(e => e.id === undefined).children;
};

const apiData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 8
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 0
  }
];

const expected = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "children": [{
        "id": 5,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "label": "List item 1",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "children": [{
            "id": 9,
            "label": "List item 1",
            "parent_id": 8
          },
          {
            "id": 10,
            "label": "List item 1",
            "parent_id": 8
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "List item 1",
    "parent_id": 0
  }
];

const unflattened = unflatten(apiData);
console.log("Matches expected? " + 
  (JSON.stringify(unflattened) === JSON.stringify(expected)));
console.log(unflattened);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That perfectly answers my question. I was stuck for more than 2 hours.

Comment: the only flaw in this code is that it adds undesired `children` elements to the original array `apiData`

Comment: this only works when the array is ordered correctly, if elements with children are at the bottom of the array, the script will be broken

Comment: @yeln This was an explicit decision that I discussed in the answer, so there's no need to call it out again in a comment. Since OP's data is well-formed, I made a judgement call to keep the algorithm simple rather than prematurely generalize, which doesn't appear to be necessary for OP's case.